# save form value in dropdown after submit

Tags: jquery, python, html, forms

I have this portion of jquery

```
function retainDropDownValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("type");
    var savedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log("DEBUGTEST");
}
```

in order to capture the values of the dropd own. I want it so that after the user clicks 
"submit," the dropdown will retain the behavior and last option in the dropdown the user chose.

```
<form action="{{URL_ROOT}}/run/search/" method="post"  id="TypeForm" onsubmit="retainDropDownValue();"  >

<select id="type" onchange="retainDropDownValue();fctCheck(this.value);" style="font-size: 25px;">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="first_selection">First</option>
   <option value="second_selection">Second</option>
</select>

Term: <input type="text" name="query" size="10" style="font-size: 25px; direction: rtl;" value="{{ query }}"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="submit" value="Search" onsubmit="submitForm();">
```

And here is the submitForm function

```
function submitForm(){
    $("#TypeForm").submit();    
}
```

What happens is it will submit and retain the textfield, but the dropdown will reset to "Select" and the '"DEBUGTEST" in the console only flashes until the submit finishes. Then it disappears.

How do I make it so that when I hit "Search" button (or type=submit button) it retains the value "first_selection" instead of resetting back to "Select" ?

Comment: You would send the page back from the server with that value selected. That all depends on your server-side code and environment.

Comment: i see...I'm using python to do this. Do you have any pointers as to how I might start with that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you submitting the page to refresh again? if so can you use ajax to submit the form hence you did not lose form selection.

Looks like when retainDropDownValue() is executed after submit, it has already lost the value which was submitted.

1. Use a variable in page level to store $('#type').val() before submitting the screen and set after submit call or onload
2. Use ajax to submit the form 
            $.ajax({
       url: form.attr('action'),
       dataType:'json',
       async:false,
       data: form.serialize(),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       success: function(data) {});

Comment: Ah I see I thought so after playing with it a bit that retainDropDownValue was losing its value. Thank you, I will try this!